# Android dialoginterface get inner dialog views

Tags: android, dialog

I've a simple program to show a dialog, with a edittext view in it, and listen to positive/negative buttons, to perform a custom action in each (read that edittext and save its content to an activity variable).

The problem arises when I can't see any way to recover my current dialog from dialog interface (and then, I can't recover any view within dialog).

Probably it's a noob question, but after some google searches, I've no one answer to it.

My code is the following

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View myView = li.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);

AlertDialog.Builder cDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
cDialog.setView(myView);
cDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.start_download, new   DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    //here the code to retrieve dialog
  }
});
cDialog.create();
```

Any clue about where can I find that?

Answer (score 80):

You can retrieve the views from the `Dialog` in the `onClick()` with:

```
EditText edit = (EditText) ((AlertDialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_view);
```

Comment: Hi slukian. I've tried to do it, but that instance is from DialogInterface class, not dialog. DialogInterface does not provide findViewById method...so it's not useful to retrieve contents of the given dialog.

Comment: @user1220817 That `dialog` parameter is the dialog that received the click. Cast it to `AlertDialog` and then call `findViewById()` like this: `EditText edit = (EditText) ((AlertDialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.editText1);`.

Comment: Oh nice! thank you a lot, did not notice that DialogInterface could be casted to dialog directly. Again, thank you :)

Answer (score 14):

This way runs perfect in my code:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

   Dialog dialog2 =Dialog.class.cast(dialog);
   EditText edit = (EditText) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.myedittext);

}
```

cheers

Answer (score 14):

You already have reference to the View that has the edit text. Why not use it directly? Just make sure you make the view final so that you can access it in the `OnClickListener` anonymous class.

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
final View myView = li.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
// don't forget to mark myView as final

AlertDialog.Builder cDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
cDialog.setView(myView);
cDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.start_download, new   DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    //here the code to retrieve dialog
    EditText edit = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_view);
  }
});
cDialog.create();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Dialog returned from method `show()` alertBuidler.

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
//...code to add methods setPositive an setNegative buttons
```

Call the `show()` method of `adb` and get `Dialog` as below:

```
final AlertDialog dialog = adb.show();
```

So you can call any button of your dialog at any point of code in your activity:

```
dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();//or
dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).performClick();//or
dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL).performClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the dialog instance with the following code:

```
  val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    builder.setMessage(R.string.eneter_url_message)
        .setView(R.layout.input_dialog)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK) { dialog, _ -> validateUrl(dialog) }
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.CANCEL) { dialog, _ -> dialog.dismiss() }
    val dialog = builder.create()
    dialog.show()
    urlInput = dialog.findViewById(R.id.urlInput)
```

Once you call *dialog.show()* then you can find any inflated views with *findViewById*

Answer (score 0):

```
     AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(navigationDrawer.getContext())
            .setView(R.layout.add_category_dialog)
            .create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

AppCompatSpinner spinner = alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.add_category_icon_selector_id);